# Syntax issue at javascript, multiple functions in one file

Tags: javascript, html

Totally noob question over here, I have this JS code where using only ONE function works perfectly, but adding a second one makes it stop working.

```
function PSN() {
    var myWindow = window.open("http://sintarjetas.com.ar/forms/psn.html", "Fran", "width=380, height=400");
}
function BLIZ() {
    var myWindow = window.open("http://sintarjetas.com.ar/forms/bliz.html", "Fran", "width=380, height=400");
}
function XLA() {
    var myWindow = window.open("http://sintarjetas.com.ar/forms/xla.html", "Fran", "width=380, height=400");
}
function STEAM() {
    var myWindow = window.open("http://sintarjetas.com.ar/forms/steam.html", "Fran", "width=380, height=400");
}
```

PSN button works ok when there's only one function written, but as I put 2 or more, all of the links stop working. 
Is it because of the syntax of this file? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What's the rest of your code that calls these functions?

Comment: Must be something else. Defining a new function with a new name doesn't cause previous functions to stop working.

Comment: When you trigger PSN, it pops open a window, when you trigger BLIZ it then replaces the content of the PSN window instead of opening a new one - are you checking the existing window?

Comment: Which browser you are checking on???

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle - works fine for us: http://jsfiddle.net/5pxxoreg/ (apart from the broken link - but the pop ups work)

Comment: The html code is <div onclick="PSN()">, that's how the functions are called. There's no existing popup, and the browser console is returning "Uncaught ReferenceError: PSN is not defined". I'm checking this on Google Chrome. Weird thing is that there's no actual difference between the jsfiddle script and my website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need multiple function to open pop up, you can just create single function and pass the `url` as param

```
function popUp(url) {
   return window.open(url, "Fran", "width=380, height=400");
}
```

**Note:** Put your functions block in `<header>` of page then try. here is [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcxc649r/)

**Update :** Since all window names are same `Fran` you will need to close the opened window first before opening other. currently it will open the url in previously opened window.

Comment: I've already made 91 functions with their corresponding onclick's in the html file, isn't there another way to fix it?
PS: F12 console is returning "Uncaught ReferenceError: PSN is not defined"

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="PSN()" title="Read More" class="btn btn-inverse btn-normal btn-primary  btn-from-left"><span data-hover="Ver más">Ver más</span></a>
Edit: Giving all windows the same name was a solution to stop the user from opening 2 forms at the same time.

Comment: make sure your `js` is before your `html code` see the updated answer

Comment: It already is, the js script is one of the first things in the header. This might be helpful, check your fiddle again, making a second link stops it from working. http://jsfiddle.net/wcxc649r/2/

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcxc649r/) is working, there was a type in function call `BLITZ`, yo have defined it as `BLIZ`

Comment: It was meant to be BLIZ because the name of the function was that one. I guess it started working because the second button called a non-existing function. 
Just in case you want to know, PSN stands for Playstation Network and Bliz for Blizzard, the website sells game accounts, cd-keys, etc. :)

Comment: Finally works: The problem was due to a syntax error at line 250. Window.open"http instead of window.open="http. I did not select this as the right answer because it solved the problem, but because it's an excelent troubleshoot for anyone having the same issues I had, in order to help him/her solve them. Thanks.